# flot pie chart toggle series not working

Tags: javascript, flot

I have applied same principal as found on this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcuC7/1/) but for pie chart it is not working

```js
var options_pie = {
  series : {
   pie:{
    show: true
   }
  },
  grid : {
   clickable : true,
   hoverable : true
  },
  legend: {
         labelFormatter: function(label, series){
          //console.log(series);
           return '<a href="#" onClick="togglePlotPie(\''+label+'\'); return false;">'+label+'</a>';
         },
         noColumns: 3,
         
     }
};



togglePlotPie = function(seriesIdx)
{
  var someData = somePlotIncidents.getData();
  var someDataActive;
  for(i=0;i < someData.length ;i++){
   if(someData[i].label == seriesIdx)
    someDataActive = i;
  }
  console.log(someData);
  console.log(someData[someDataActive].pie.show);
  someData[someDataActive].pie.show = !someData[someDataActive].pie.show;
  console.log(someData[someDataActive].pie.show);
 /* if(someData[someDataActive].stack == 1)
   someData[someDataActive].stack = 0;
  else if(someData[someDataActive].stack == 0)
   someData[someDataActive].stack = 1;
  *///console.log(someData[seriesIdx].bars);
  console.log(someData);
  somePlotIncidents.setData(someData);
  somePlotIncidents.setupGrid();
  somePlotIncidents.draw();
}



var datasets = [{label:"P1",data:167,color:0,idx:0},{label:"P2",data:647,color:1,idx:1},{label:"P3",data:766,color:2,idx:2}];

somePlotIncidents = $.plot($("#network-graph"), datasets, options_pie);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>

<div id="network-graph" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
```

Comment: Setting the show option per data series doesn't work for pie charts. Copy the data and skip deactivated parts to change the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way for Pie charts. I made a few changes to the dataset to make it work. Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/abhash2610/x0cgekfm/).
I have added 2 more property for each pie.

```
var datasets = [{
  label: "P1",
  data: 167,    // this value is updated along with show 
  color: 0,
  idx: 0,
  show: true,
  oldData: 167   // this value is copied back to data on toggle
}, {
  label: "P2",
  data: 647,
  color: 1,
  idx: 1,
  show: true,
  oldData: 647
}, {
  label: "P3",
  data: 766,
  color: 2,
  idx: 2,
  show: true,
  oldData: 766
}];
```